# Neo4J order by count relationships extremely slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to model a large knowledge graph. (using v3.1.1).

My actual graph contains only two types of Nodes (`Topic`, `Properties`) and a single type of Relationships (`HAS_PROPERTIES`).

The count of nodes is about 85M (47M `:Topic`, the rest of nodes are `:Properties`).

I'm trying to get the most connected node:Topic for this. I'm using the following query:

```
MATCH (n:Topic)-[r]-()
RETURN n, count(DISTINCT r) AS num
ORDER BY num
```

This query or almost any query I try to perform  (without filtering the results) using the count(relationships) and order by count(relationships) is always extremely slow: these queries take more than 10 minutes and still no response.

Am i missing indexes or is the a better syntax?

Is there any chance i can execute this query in a reasonable time?

Comment: What does your config (heap/pagecache look like) how much memory do you have, what kind of disk?

Comment: `:Properties` nodes sounds scary, in a property graph you store the properties with the nodes :)

Comment: You should also limit your results if you are trying to run it in browser or shell, otherwise you get 47M records returned which blows up your browser or terminal (or even the pre-processing in each)

Comment: Here is the config i'm using:
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=6G
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=3G
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=6g
Disk is SSD, Between the description i've represented i not exactly the actual model i'm using, but i just tried to represent somehting extremely simple :) and i appreciate your interest :)

Comment: how big is your graph on disk?

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
MATCH (n:Topic)
RETURN n, size( (n)--() ) AS num
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Which reads the degree from a node directly.

Comment: Still slow and no response since 4 minutes now :/